# Get SQL Azure database Edition and Service_Objective using TSQL

Tags: t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

Does anyone know how to get an Azure database's Edition (Standard, etc.) and Service_Objective (S1, S2, etc) using TSQL? I can find PowerShell and Portal explanations but I cannot find any reference to TSQL.

Comment: SQL Azure does not support a full range of TSQL commands.  most Database Operations in Azure are only available through the Azure Service Management API.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this query to check the Service Edition of the Database:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('Database_Name', 'EDITION')
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('Database_Name', 'ServiceObjective')
```

If the `ServiceObjective` line is not working, there can be various reasons for that:

1. You might be trying to get service objective for editions that don't have serviceobjective defined. For example, Web Edition. In case of Web Edition, ServiceObjective should return null.
2. As [Satya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4760004/satya-msft) mentioned in their comment, this works only for V12 servers. So if you are trying to run this command on servers prior to V12, this command will not work.

Answer (score 10):

**Update**
*I've recently switched to using the Azure system table `sys.database_service_objectives`. This allows me to also retrieve the SQL Database Elastic Pool name in a single query. Original answer still recorded below for convenience.*

```
SELECT @@VERSION AS AzureVersion,
  db_name() AS [Name],
  edition AS AzureEdition,
  service_objective AS AzureTier,
  elastic_pool_name AS ElasticPool
FROM sys.database_service_objectives
```

***Original Answer***

I like to grab all three values at once, using `db_name()` to point at the current database, and replacing the `NULL` ServiceObjective with a more useful message for v11 servers.

```
SELECT @@VERSION AS AzureVersion,
DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Edition') AS AzureEdition,
COALESCE(DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'ServiceObjective'), 'N/A in v11') AS AzureTier
```

Comment: Fantastic query Dusty

Comment: if your active database connection is "Master" then this query works a bit better IMHO:

SELECT top (10000) d.name, dso.* FROM sys.database_service_objectives dso
INNER JOIN sys.databases d on d.database_id = dso.database_id